# javascript library / jquery plugin that enables me to click on a list of tags to input them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tags

I've searched a lot and all the tag input plugins I can find are like this one: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

You can type in the input box and it wraps the tags in nice styles and offers auto-completion and stuff.

But what I want is this:

I have a list of recommendated tags. The plugin makes the tags clickable. When I click on one tag, the tag goes into the input box. When I click on the tag again, the tag is removed from the input box.

Of course, the input box still needs to function as a normal input box, i.e., I can still type in it.

It's like the tagging on https://delicious.com/ and http://diigo.com/.

Is there a plugin to do this?

Comment: theres no plugin for that... you need to write your own custom plugin for that implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this effect?
this effect no jquery method,this is js code.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jikeytang/bRxCX/2/)

```
var navs = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('li');
var tmp = navs[navs.length-1];
for(var i=0; i<navs.length; i++){
    navs[i].onclick = function(){
        tmp.className = '';
        this.className = 'current';
        tmp = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked your demo, but I didn't see an input box. Perhaps I didn't make my question clear enough?

Comment: Thanks. This one looks good. But the input box still needs to function as a normal input box, i.e., I should still be able to type in it.

Comment: This cannot be completely with input, only one additional behind. [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jikeytang/EJgXX/2/)

Comment: Then when I want to get the value, I need to get the value of the div plus the value of the input. I know now. Thank you.